# Joomla 4 with horizontal menu on 2 rows

Tags: drop-down-menu, joomla, bootstrap-5, nav

I'm using Joomla 4 with a Cassiopeia theme (actually child theme of Cassiopeia)
I would like to have the menu on 2 horizontal rows.
When I add an item to the menu it oversizes the nav container on the right side, not going automatically down on the second row.
I suppose this is normal behavior coming from [Bootstrap 5 nav](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav).

> Navigation in navbars will also grow to occupy as much horizontal
> space as possible

So far I can make it using 2 menus and 2 modules in the `menu` position.
The drawback is having two 'hamburger' menus on small screens.
So, is there a simple way to have items on two-row menu?

Answer (score -1):

```
 .container-header .mod-menu {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

above code in `user.css` did the trick.